# Aggregate objects in DDD

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, domain-driven-design

Can I use the same aggregate class as a member in other classes?
And if yes would the class that contains the aggregate enforce access etc on that?

Let say you have a User class. Then a class named LogBook and at last a class named Log/Post (something down that alley). The LogBook would be an aggregate root for the Log/Post class and the User would be the overall aggregate in my example. Now, would the User class contain methods for adding log-posts etc? You would make one method in the User class that invokes LogBook class which has a method that does all the logic for actually adding a log.

Or, is a aggregate ALWAYS on top of the hierachy? No nesting.

Comment: Bob, that doesn't sound like a good idea. Can you give an example of what you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a nice [definition](http://domaindrivendesign.org/node/88) of an Aggregate:

> Definition: A cluster of associated objects that are treated as a unit
>   for the purpose of data changes. External references are restricted to
>   one member of the Aggregate, designated as the root. A set of
>   consistency rules applies within the Aggregate's boundaries. Problem:
>   It is difficult to guarantee the consistency of changes to objects in
>   a model with complex associations. Invariants need to be maintained
>   that apply to closely related groups of objects, not just discrete
>   objects. Yet cautious locking schemes cause multiple users to
>   interfere pointlessly with each other and make a system unusable.
>   [DDD, p. 126] Solution: Cluster the Entities and Value Objects into
>   Aggregates and define boundaries around each. Choose one Entity to be
>   the root of each Aggregate, and control all access to the objects
>   inside the boundary through the root. Allow external objects to hold
>   references to root only. Transient references to the internal members
>   can be passed out for use within a single operation only. Because the
>   root controls access, it cannot be blindsided by changes to the
>   internals. This arrangemens makes it practical to enforce all
>   invariants for objects in the Aggregate and for the Aggregate as a
>   whole in any state change. [DDD, p. 129]

I don't think you want the User class reaching into the LogBook's aggregated objects without going through the LogBook class. However, accessing the LogBook from User seems OK.

Comment: Yes, so a User would have methods that does action based on the Users members, this case the LogBook. Now do I need to get a hold of the logbook through the User and then use the reference to the users logbook to to further actions instead of making a method in User class named addPost() which uses the internal logbook member to do actually add the post?

Comment: I'm reluctant to say what you "should" do, but if you can manipulate LogBook Posts through the User, then User would be the aggregate root of the LogBook by the DDD definition.

Comment: But is it better to return the LogBook through the User and then act on that reference?

Comment: And can aggregates be associated with other classes as member references?

Comment: I think returning the LogBook through the User is OK. How you get a root object is less important than the fact that everything within that aggregate goes through the root object. As far as references to aggregate root within other aggregates, I would try to avoid that by just having an identifier that you then go look that related aggregate up with. Otherwise, you could end up with an object graph that loads your entire database.

Comment: I did some further reading and I know understand how the aggregate objects are intended to use. Thank you for your help Eric :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the internals of an aggregate are allowed to hold references to the **root** of other aggregates. But each aggregate is responsible for enforcing its own boundaries. There is nothing stopping other objects from accessing the "referenced" aggregate completely outside of the first one - i.e. I don't think that nesting or ownership is implied just because one aggregate references another.

In your example, it seems like LogBook would fit better as an aggregate, controlling access to posts. Trying to shoehorn this into a larger User aggregate seems to be an awkward factoring of responsibilities.

Comment: So does this mean that a User class can have a method named addLogPost() and that method invokes the addLog() on the LogBook class which the User class has a member to?